# RaisePropertyChanged not updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, windows-phone

I'm having trouble getting my UI to update Two Listboxes' to update properly when my ViewModel changes.

First, the basic logic behind the page:

Movie is an object with a title, and a variety of `MovieDetails`. Some `MovieDetail` are different than others, as they are *detailed* which is a glorified way of saying they're more Important.
I use two `ListBoxes` to separate these `MovieDetails` into *stacked* `ListBoxes`, one for 'Detailed' and one for 'NotDetailed'
If a movie has no 'Detailed' attributes, the corresponding list is Hidden via a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` (and vice-versa)

When I navigate to the page, I set the `Movie` the page corresponds to, and it should `RaisePropertyChanged` to alert the `AllMoviesDetail` `ObservableCollection` that it should re-get `Movies.MovieDetailFetchedList`.
From there, `AllMoviesDetail` would alert the two `ObservableCollections (Detailed, NotDetailed)` they should be re-`get`.

In fact, `RaisePropertyChanged` on `NotDetailedMovieDetails` or `DetailedMovieDetails` does not seem to do anything either. (And the corresponding `HasNotDetailedMovieDetails, Has...`)

What does work, however, is if I add more items into the list, the CollectionChanged event seems to fire and reactivate the list. I have also been able to do this by instantiating the `ObservableCollections` in code first `var temp = DetailedMoviesDetail;`

```
public class MoviesDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Property Names

    public const string MoviePropertyString = "Movie";
    public const string AllMoviesDetailPropertyString = "AllMoviesDetail";
    public const string DetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString = "DetailedMoviesDetail";
    public const string NotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString = "NotDetailedMoviesDetail";
    public const string HasNotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString = "HasNotDetailedMoviesDetail";
    public const string HasDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString = "HasDetailedMoviesDetail";
    public const string NotDetailedHeaderPropertyString = "NotDetailedHeader";

    #endregion


    public MoviesDetailViewModel()
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            Movie = DesignDataStore.MovieList[0];
            Movie.Category = Category.DDA;
        }
    }

    private Movie _Movie;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Movie for which to browse MoviesDetail. It is expected when setting this property, that MoviesDetail for it have been downloaded previously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The 'Master' property for this ViewModel. All properties are Dependent on this and the underlying property MoviesDetailList</remarks>
    /// <seealso cref="MovieDetailFetchedList"/>
    public Movie Movie
    {
        get { return _Movie; }
        set
        {
            if (_Movie != value)
            {
                if (_Movie != null)
                    _Movie.MovieDetailFetchedList.CollectionChanged -= MoviesDetailListChanged;


                _Movie = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged(MoviePropertyString);
                RaisePropertyChanged(StatementPeriodAvailablePropertyString);
                RaisePropertyChanged(NotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
                Movie.MovieDetailFetchedList.CollectionChanged += MoviesDetailListChanged;

                RaisePropertyChanged(AllMoviesDetailPropertyString);

                RaisePropertyChanged(DetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);

                RaisePropertyChanged(NotDetailedHeaderPropertyString);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoviesDetailListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (((MovieDetail) item).IsDetailed())
                    DetailedMoviesDetail.Add(item as MovieDetail);
                else
                    NotDetailedMoviesDetail.Add(item as MovieDetail);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(AllMoviesDetailPropertyString);
            RaisePropertyChanged(DetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
            RaisePropertyChanged(NotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
        }
    }




    #endregion

    private MovieDetailFetchedList _allMoviesDetail;
    public MovieDetailFetchedList AllMoviesDetail
    {
        get
        {
            if (Movie == null)
                return new MovieDetailFetchedList();

            return _allMoviesDetail ?? (AllMoviesDetail = Movie.MovieDetailFetchedList);
        }
        set
        {
            if (_allMoviesDetail != value)
            {
                if (_allMoviesDetail != null)
                    _allMoviesDetail.CollectionChanged -= MoviesDetailListChanged;
                _allMoviesDetail = value;
                _allMoviesDetail.CollectionChanged += MoviesDetailListChanged;

                RaisePropertyChanged(AllMoviesDetailPropertyString);
                //force update
                DetailedMoviesDetail = NotDetailedMoviesDetail = null;
                RaisePropertyChanged(DetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
                RaisePropertyChanged(HasDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
                RaisePropertyChanged(NotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
                RaisePropertyChanged(HasNotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
            }

        }
    }

    public bool HasNotDetailedMoviesDetail { get { return NotDetailedMoviesDetail != null && NotDetailedMoviesDetail.Count > 0; } }



    private ObservableCollection<MovieDetail> _notDetailedMoviesDetail;
    public ObservableCollection<MovieDetail> NotDetailedMoviesDetail
    {
        get
        {
            if (Movie == null) return new ObservableCollection<MovieDetail>();

            return AllMoviesDetail;
               return _notDetailedMoviesDetail ?? //make sure RaisePropertyChanged happens by using property setter
              (NotDetailedMoviesDetail = AllMoviesDetail.Where(mem => !mem.IsDetailed()).ToObservableCollection());
        }
        set
        {
            _notDetailedMoviesDetail = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(NotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
            RaisePropertyChanged(HasNotDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
        }
    }

    public bool HasDetailedMoviesDetail
    { get { return DetailedMoviesDetail != null && DetailedMoviesDetail.Count > 0; } }

    private ObservableCollection<MovieDetail> _DetailedMoviesDetail;
    public ObservableCollection<MovieDetail> DetailedMoviesDetail
    {
        get
        {
            if (Movie == null) return new ObservableCollection<MovieDetail>();

            return AllMoviesDetail;
            return _DetailedMoviesDetail ?? //make sure RaisePropertyChanged happens by using property setter
            (DetailedMoviesDetail = AllMoviesDetail.Where(mem => mem.IsDetailed()).ToObservableCollection());
        }
        set
        {
            _DetailedMoviesDetail = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(DetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
            RaisePropertyChanged(HasDetailedMoviesDetailPropertyString);
        }
    }


    private string _DetailedHeader;
    public string DetailedHeader
    {
        get { return _DetailedHeader ?? (_DetailedHeader = AppResources.in_available); }
        set { _DetailedHeader = value; }
    }

    public string NotDetailedHeader
    {
        get { return (Movie != null && Movie.Category == Category.DRAMA) ? AppResources.Movie_MoviesDetail : AppResources.not_in_available; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question.  It'd be even more helpful, though, if you could provide a smaller code sample that reproduces your problem, though.  And in many cases, the process of preparing a minimal example will give you the insight needed to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Also include the code that shows the class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your property getters (except `AllMoviesDetail`) have *two* return statements. Since only the first will be executed, the values are not being assigned and the PropertyChanged events are not being twiggered.

Comment: Is it an issue with having 2 statements that can leave to different code executing? How should I handle this given that the objects are accessed (through binding via the `NavigationContext`) before they will actually work?

Comment: @willmel - A return statement will end execution at that point. The usual pattern is not to calculate in the `get` but to calculate in a central point and then raise the appropriate property change events.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand it doesn't really make sense for the getter to become a setter -- but how would It be rewritten so that the `Binding` works properly before the `Movie` object is set? i.e. if I'm setting My Movie object based on the QueryString in `OnNavigatedTo`, the UI has already been processed and the binding has already happened (to a invalid Value, as Movie has not been set yet). Thanks.. your response is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there actually a flicker before the UI is updated (ie. have you tested it)? If so, bind the visibility of the container to a `Loading` property that you can set to `false` when the data has been located. You could even display a "loading" progress bar if you wanted.

Comment: Well, Movies.MovieList is null (because Movies is null) which throws a NullReferenceException. The UI itself isn't really the issue, but rather the binding

Comment: @willmel - The binding shouldn't throw a NullReferenceException, XAML bindings automatically detect null values and stop attempting to bind the property chain.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions. The binding itself doesn't, but `AllMoviesDetail.Where(mem => !mem.IsDetailed()).ToObservableCollection())` will, which is what DetailedMoviesDetails is.